# Conformal cobblestones

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Open-ended question:

It strikes me that the cobblestone pattern known as Bogen, which can be seen in many European cities, is a fairly accurate representation of the conformal mapping defined by the complex function $f(z) = \ln(z)$:

[image: cobblestones]

Conformal mappings make a good basis for such patterns because of their angle-preserving property, which means that a square grid is mapped onto a curvilinear orthogonal grid which can be easily constructed from an arrangement of square cobblestones (setts).

The curves in the Bogen pattern are *catenaries of equal strength*. They are described by $\xi = c - \ln{\cos{\eta}}$ and $\xi = c - \ln{\sin{\eta}}$, where $f(z) = \xi + i\eta$ and $c$ is a real constant.

Other conformal mapping functions commonly seen in cobblestones are $f(z) = z$ (rectilinear) and $f(z) = e^z$ (circular). But which other functions would be suitable, and which have actually been used?

[Edit: function definitions inverted to conform to usual convention.]

Comment: FYI: there's a conformal-geometry tag which you may find appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which have been used but you may find these interesting:

1. $f(z) = \sin(z)$ :

Vertical and horizontal lines are mapped to hyperbolas and ellipses.

[image]

2. Another interesting map is $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$
   [image]

[Here is the source](http://www.webassign.net/zillengmath4/20.2.pdf) to these images which also explain about it in a deeper manner.

3. You may also find interest at [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), which maps circles and lines to circles and lines:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY

Another interesting article related:
http://resonanceswavesandfields.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/5-detailed-conformal-mappings.html